# Pointer Event/Hover change size or disable

Tags: html, css, hover

When you hover over the "related articles" section of the page - the hover effect creates a huge red box - is there a way I can make it the same size as the article preview or disable it if not?

http://insightcxo.com/5-ways-to-increase-profit-this-year/

It works fine on the homepage though:

http://insightcxo.com/

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your css as follows:

```
.related-item figure {
    background-color: #222222;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

This will make it behave like the one's present in your homepage.

Comment: Hey taxicala - you are amazing.